# Print function call result in lldb

Tags: macos, printing, wxwidgets, lldb

I'm trying to debug a program on OSX with lldb.

Below is the screenshot of the lldb session:

[image]

What I wonder is how come the message box shows the results, while lldb "print" function does not.

And how do I get a value from lldb "print" function?

I'm not familiar at all with lldb (I mostly use Linux with gdb) so need help/guidance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why dont you just use an IDE?

Comment: @macroland, I'm using Xcode to make the build, but when I try to run the program it crashes...

Comment: Which line causes crash? Have you started debugging from the very start (app initialization part)? It is very hard to understand from the image.

Comment: @macroland, this one is about using lldb directly from the Terminal, And yes - I started from the beginning as `lldb myprogram.app` and then `break set -f ... -l ...`,. But lldb is different from gdb and so trying to print the result of function call doesn't work as I expected...

Comment: So, here it is not a crash, but wrong value.

Comment: @macroland, and if you want to help with Xcode crash - I made https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75265455/loading-the-library-from-bundle-vs-compiled-location

Comment: sorry not familiar with XCode. I am using VS and have no such problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an Xcode vrs. command-line lldb thing.  IIUC, this question is about how to show a "user-friendly" representation of a type whose bare ivars aren't all that helpful.  You'd see the same not terribly helpful "raw" view in the Xcode locals window as results from the `p` command.

In cases where lldb knows about a type's internal representation, (e.g. for most of the common `std` types) it uses "summary or synthetic child providers" to show a user-friendly view.  For instance, there's a summary provider for `std::string` that prints the string contents. But lldb doesn't have any built-in knowledge of wxString, so it only shows the raw fields, which aren't terribly illuminating from the outside.

It looks like wxStrings can render themselves; you could try something like:

```
(lldb) p labelFont.GetFaceName().ToASCII()
```

if you want to get a human-readable rendering of the wxString (presumably that's what wxMessageBox does as well.)

If you use these "wx" entities a lot, you might try your hand at writing data formatters for them to make your life more convenient.  Information for doing that is here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html#summary-strings

Comment: @Igor, Maybe my two cents: use std::wstring and std::string and only use wxString when interacting with wxWidget's GUI items.